# How do load balancer's handle situations where all servers are busy?

Tags: load-balancing

Consider the case where a load balancer is connected to 10 servers, each of which runs a single web server process that is single threaded. Handling a request takes 10 seconds.

Now the load balancer receives 10 requests in the span of 2 seconds. When an eleventh request comes in, what happens?

1. The load balancer realizes that all the servers are busy, and waits until one of them completes their task before forwarding the request to that server
2. The load balancer immediately forwards the request to one of the servers, despite it being busy.

I'm having trouble finding information on which of the two above scenarios is correct. Thanks for your help!